# Module not found despite being in @INC

Tags: perl, catalyst

Perl is complaining that it can't find a module that is right there in @INC.

```
Can't locate <module> in @INC (@INC contains etc.)
```

@INC is set correctly, and the module is right there where it should be. This is a web app running under catalyst, and it runs fine in other installations. Something is funky about this one server setup. I've checked permissions on the files, they are fine.

Any suggestions about what else it could be?

As requested in the comments, adding some more info:

In one of my Catalyst controllers, I am "use"-ing a module external to the Catalyst app: Template::Plugin::I18n. I get the following error:

```
Can't locate Template::Plugin::I18n in @INC (@INC contains:  
  /webroot/www-dev/sonnet/lib    /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.12.4/BSDPAN
  /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4/mach /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4
  /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.12.4/mach /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.12.4 . /usr/local) at 
  /webroot/www-dev/sonnet/lib/Sonnet/Controller/Pubs.pm line 647.
```

The module is found at /webroot/www-dev/sonnet/lib/Template/Plugin/I18n.pm with the same permissions as the rest of the app.

Comment: Perhaps you should share a few more details about your setup.

Comment: Without knowing a bit more information no one is going to be able to give you a definitive answer.  I will note that I ran into similar problems with the ultimate culprit being SELinux.  [See this blog post for more info.](http://studyofcrying.blogspot.com/2011/03/apache-2-modperl-htmlmason-use-lib-and.html)

Comment: I'm not really sure what to share ... I asked bc I'm at a bit of a loss. Server is running: Apache/2.2.21 (FreeBSD) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8e DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.12.4. Thanks for the SELinux suggestion ... I'll look into that.

Comment: You are telling your conclusions ("the module is right there", "@INC is set correctly"), but we want non-judgemental observations instead. Chances are that you misunderstand something, and by looking at the original data we can find the problem. [Edit the question to add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9205648/edit) the information: a dump of `@INC`, perhaps `perl -V`; exactly how you added/installed the module, how it is loaded into the Catalyst app, how the relevant of the file system tree looks like where the module resides.

Comment: You'll also get that error if the user as which the script runs does not have permission to access the .pm file (either because it does not have access to the .pm file itself, or because it doesn't have access to one of its parent directories).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing. I had a stray "require" statement that had quotes around the package name! That was causing the error, even though the statement was unneccessary as well. Too much late night coding. Sorry for the distraction. All your suggestions are much appreciated!